# PHP: Convert string to array With special requirements

Tags: php

How can i create array from file that have long string?

My string looks like:

115 = c

116 = a

etc...

Each line is the same.

i want to have array like this:
"115"=>"c"
"116"=>"a"

Comment: Why did you name your variables like `115`. `116` etc. in the first place?

Comment: HI @Rajdeep Paul i did not. i get the file from some company. each line have product code and product name

Comment: Break up the string by newlines into key-value pairs, then parse those (split around `=`) and add them to your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're question is not really understandable as such, and lacks proper formatting, pointers to what you've tried, or points your code is failing at. SO is not here to write things for you, but correct and guide you. That said, if you want to read contents from a file and work with it you could do something like this:

```
// Readonly open a file, and handle it line per line
$newArray = array();
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        $lineExploded = explode('=', $line);
        $newArray[ trim($lineExploded[0]) ] = trim($lineExploded[1]);
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```